# Select ID of smallest row in group using SQL Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

My question is similar to: 
[How do you group by one column and retrieve a row with the minimum value of another column in T/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212093/how-do-you-group-by-one-column-and-retrieve-a-row-with-the-minimum-value-of-anot)

First of all: I'm using SQL Server Compact which makes the SQL quite restrictive.

I have two tables and a many to many relation between them: Rooms and Courses. From a list of rooms I want to check if the room is unoccupied in a specified time range, what course is now in this room and what's the next course in this room. The first two parts are no problem:

```sql
SELECT a.Id, COUNT(c.Id) AS ConflictingCourses, d.Id AS CurrentCourseId
FROM Rooms AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RoomCourses AS b ON b.RoomId = a.Id
    -- Conflicting Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS c ON c.Id = b.CourseId AND @startTime <= c.EndTime AND @endTime >= c.StartTime
    -- Current Course  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS d ON d.Id = b.CourseId AND @now <= d.EndTime AND @now >= d.StartTime 
WHERE (a.Id IN (1,2,3,4))
GROUP BY a.RoomId, d.Id
```

Now to the problem: I want to get the first course which has the StartTime after now. To get this course I try to join all courses which will follow. From this result I thought it would be easy to get the next course because for each group it's the ID of the row which has the smalles date:

```sql
SELECT a.Id, COUNT(c.Id) AS ConflictingCourses, d.Id AS CurrentCourseId
FROM Rooms AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RoomCourses AS b ON b.RoomId = a.Id
    -- Conflicting Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS c ON c.Id = b.CourseId AND @startTime <= c.EndTime AND @endTime >= c.StartTime
    -- Current Course  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS d ON d.Id = b.CourseId AND @now <= d.EndTime AND @now >= d.StartTime 
    -- All Upcoming Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS e ON e.Id = b.CourseId AND e.StartTime >= @now
WHERE (a.Id IN (1,2,3,4))
GROUP BY a.RoomId, d.Id
```

But I can only get the startTime of the next course using MIN(e.StartTime). But I want the Id of the row which the MIN(e.StartTime) belongs to. I tried hundreds of combinations, workarounds and other stuff only to get the ID of the upcoming course. The main problem is that SQL CE does not support subquerys which return scalar values and therefore I cannot receive any information which would allow me to only get the next course.

Any ideas how I could get the upcoming course of a room?

Comment: Can you post your definition of `CourseSet`?

Comment: CourseSet is like the Courses, I just missed to change the table name for the example. 
Table Rooms has: Id, RoomName; 
Table Courses has: Id, StartTime, EndTime; 
Table RoomCourse has: RoomId, CourseId

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
SELECT a.Id, COUNT(c.Id) AS ConflictingCourses, d.Id AS CurrentCourseId
FROM Rooms AS a 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RoomCourses AS b ON b.RoomId = a.Id
    -- Conflicting Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS c ON c.Id = b.CourseId AND @startTime <= c.EndTime AND @endTime >= c.StartTime
    -- Current Course  
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS d ON d.Id = b.CourseId AND @now <= d.EndTime AND @now >= d.StartTime 
    -- All Upcoming Courses
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS e ON e.Id IN (SELECT MIN(Id) 
                                             FROM Courses
                                             WHERE Id = b.CourseId
                                               AND e.StartTime >= @now)
WHERE (a.Id IN (1,2,3,4))
GROUP BY a.RoomId, d.Id
```

I know the IN has no use here since the query will always return only 1 result but it apparently is a workaround for this kind of situation (SQL CE).

Comment: @Danielku15: Can you please provide feedback and votes if applicable on this? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I checked out the SQL and it doesn't work. I tried to execute the query and it timed out. But in addition: By filtering the ID to the b.CourseId in the subselect I would only get a single result storing b.CourseId. This way the statement is the same as in: 
"LEFT OUTER JOIN Courses AS e on e.Id = b.CourseId" . This statement only gets me the current course in the lookup iteration, not all reffered courses in the resultSet of "b".

Comment: @Danielku15: You are right, MIN(Id) will always equal b.CourseId. Could you provide your table definitions (columns) and some data sample (fake data if needed) just to give us a better understanding of what you are working with?