# comparing same table in sql nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

If a data table is the following

```
Name cgpa dept
a     4.0   x
b     3.9   x
c     3.8   x
d     3.8   y
e     4.0   y
f     3.9   z
g     3.6   z
```

Select names and cgpa of those students whose cgpa is higher than all other students in the same department:

```
select NAME, CGPA
from STD_INFO T1
where CGPA > all
(
select CGPA 
from STD_INFO T2
where lower(T2.DEPT)=lower(T1.DEPT)
and T2.STD_NO != T1.STD_NO
);
```

I need to understand the full simulation.....please help me with this....and what is it called when we compare same table naming like above(t1,t2) ??

Comment: This won't work if two students have the same GPA and they're both the highest. Which name would you show?

Comment: actually i am new to sql....i have browsed the internet to understand the simulation but no luck.....if u can please elaborate what is happening here.....i mean the simulation

Comment: My solution below will return both highest students in a department given a tie CGPA.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find the `max(CGPA)` per `DEPT` and `inner join` that data set to your `STD_INFO` table:

```
select s1.NAME,s1.CGPA
from STD_INFO as s1
  inner join (select DEPT,max(CGPA) as CGPA
              from STD_INFO
              group by DEPT) as s2
    on s2.DEPT = s1.DEPT
    and s2.CGPA = s1.CGPA;
```

[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83297/4)

Comment: This has a different result from the original query, though, when there is more than one student with the maximum cgpa in a department. (See my comment on LCIII's answer for elaboration.)

Answer (score 0):

You loop through all records in table std_info, which you call t1. For each record you check whether their cgpa is greater than all cgpas selected in the subquery.

In the subquery you select again from table std_info, which you call t2 this time. So with one t1 record you select all records from the table with the same department (`lower(T2.DEPT)=lower(T1.DEPT)`) but another student number (`T2.STD_NO != T1.STD_NO`).

If all other students in the department have a cgpa lower than the student you are currently looking at, then you keep that student in your result list, otherwise you remove it from it.

So after having checked all students you remain with those whose cgpa is higher than all other students in the same department.

The only "name" I can think of for this is: This is a correlated subquery on the same table.

The use of > ALL (or SOME or ANY for that matter) is very rare. Most often you use EXISTS or IN instead:

```
select NAME, CGPA
from STD_INFO T1
where not exists
(
  select *
  from STD_INFO T2
  where lower(T2.DEPT)=lower(T1.DEPT)
  and T2.STD_NO != T1.STD_NO
  and T2.CGPA  >= T1.CGPA 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Select names and cgpa of those students whose cgpa is higher than all other students in the same department:

If two students have the same GPA you'll have to show both records otherwise the systems won't know which name to show since they're both "top" of their department. Like in this example:

```
Name  cgpa  dept
a     4.0   x
b     4.0   x
r     3.1   x
c     3.8   y
e     3.5   y
d     3.9   z
```

This query:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN (
SELECT MAX(cgpa) AS 'cgpa',dept FROM table AS t2
GROUP BY dept) AS innerTable
ON innerTable.cgpa = t.cgpa AND innerTable.dept = t.dept
```

Will return this:

```
Name cgpa dept
a    4    x
b    4    x
c    3.8  y
d    3.9  z
```

The answer here is very similar to this one: [How do you group by one column and retrieve a row with the minimum value of another column in T/SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1212093/1439748)

Comment: Well, if two or more students have the maximum cgpa, then "cgpa is higher than all other students in the same department" is simply not true for them and they are not being shown with the original query. There is nothing wrong with that. You are showing a slightly different query where you show all students whose cgpa is the maximum in their department.